# T(Running Time) vs T (Recursion)

Tags: algorithm, performance, recursion, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

I don't understand whats the difference between the (T) from recurrence and the (T) from Running Time. I took some courses that teach me recursion and lineal recurrence, for example in this code

```
factorial (n) {    
if (n = 0) 
    return 1
else
    return n * factorial(n-1)
}
```

Why the time complexity is O(n) ?

I took a course about recurrence and I'm a little confuse. I would analize the code in this way:

```
Tn = 1 , n=0

Tn = n*T(n-1)
```

so if we expand the recurssion :

```
Tn = (n-1)*(n)*T(n-2)
```

so the recurssion grow n! and the growth is `O(n!)`, however, the analysis is different, but what am I doing wrong?

And then I've another similar question , I took a linear recurrence function course and in these course I learn how to solve a recurrence for example : `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)`

So in the fibanicci program:

```
def Fibonacci(n): 
if n<0: 
    print("Incorrect input") 
# First Fibonacci number is 0 
elif n==0: 
    return 0
# Second Fibonacci number is 1 
elif n==1: 
    return 1
else: 
    return Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2)
```

I would solve the fibonacci linear recurrence with a close form like these:

```
1/sqr(5)*(1+sqr(5))/2 *((1+sqr(5))/2)**n  -  1/sqr(5)*(1-sqr(5))/2 *((1-sqr(5))/2)**n
```

**Why would the order of growth not be? O(1/sqr(5)*(1+sqr(5))/2 *((1+sqr(5))/2)**n)**

Comment: The time equation should be `T(n) = 1 + T(n-1)` instead of `T(n) = n * T(n-1)`. The latter is just the factorial formula rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between the value of the function and the time to compute that value.

When you analyze your linear recurrence, you claim that the analysis is:

Tn = 1 , n=0
Tn = n*T(n-1)

But the computation involved in computing each next term is really just 1 (one multiplication) given the previous values. So it should be Tn = 1 + T(n-1). When you rerun your analysis, the linear result will become clear.

---

A similar separation between the value and the runtime will help you analyze your second question.

Comment: Why sometimes the value of a recursive function can be similar to the execution time of the same function, or rather what relationship do they both have?.Sometimes I see my professor analyze the recursive function and in the end it ends up being the runtime